# Defining static vectors

Tags: vector, static, global-variables, rust

I'm attempting to define a static `Vec` with a struct of my own design for global use in my program (and yes, it does need to be mutable), but I get one of two errors. When given a constructor, the compiler complains and doesn't compile:

```
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData> = Vec::new();
```

```
error: mutable statics are not allowed to have destructors [E0397]
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData> = Vec::new();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
error: statics are not allowed to have destructors [E0493]
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData> = Vec::new();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
error: function calls in statics are limited to struct and enum constructors [E0015]
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData> = Vec::new();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
note: a limited form of compile-time function evaluation is available on a nightly compiler via `const fn`
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData> = Vec::new();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

and when I omit the constructor as I would in, say, Java, I get another complaint:

```
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData>;
```

```
error: expected one of `!`, `+`, `::`, or `=`, found `;`
static mut stamps: Vec<StampedData>;
                                   ^
```

I understand from these errors that I can't declare globally, then initialize later, nor can I initialize a static, mutable vector. Would the best course of action be to make the variable in `main()` and pass a pointer to the functions that need it?

Comment: *Would the best course of action be to make the variable in `main()` and pass a pointer to the functions that need it?* — 100% yes.

Comment: *When given a destructor...* - did you mean **constructor**? A *destructor* is code that is run when the object is deallocated.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the affirmation of my pointer idea, and yes, you're correct, I guess I was thinking destructor due to the error